# Are there any good video lectures for learning general relativity at the level of Hobson?

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations

> Before answering, please see [**our policy**](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4698) on
>   resource recommendation questions. Please try to give substantial answers that detail the
>   **style, content, and prerequisites** of the book or paper (or other resource). Explain what the
>   resource is like as much as you can; that way the reader can decide which one is most suited
>   for them rather than blindly relying on the suggestions of others. Answers which just suggest a book
>   or paper may be deleted.
>
> And please, note that any answers to this are **community-owned**, which means that they are subject to heavy editing, especially to make them comply with the book policy, to avoid deletion.
>
> This question specifically asks for the level to be that of **Hobson**.

Are there any good video lectures for learning general relativity at the level of Hobson?
The internet has by L. Susskind, but it is a simple level. I found good one here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hcTNxJF_AjU&list=SPB11E80403FB98CFF
however, the acoustics is a little bit not so good.

Answer (score 1):

Lectures by Ashoke Sen are very deep and insightful. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mBytE2daw3k

Comment: It would be nice if you could would shortly address *why* these lecture are deep/insightful/relevant to the topic at hand. Link-only answers are frowned upon.